# Pyramid Chart Using Echart

Tags: javascript, echarts

i have this javascript code, to generate a gender pyramid chart the type bar of female in right and the male in left with count and not with positive value this my chart :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5UCq.png)

```
    option = {
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {            // Use axis to trigger tooltip
            type: 'shadow'        // 'shadow' as default; can also be 'line' or 'shadow'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        data: ['Female', 'Male']
    },
    grid: {
        left: '3%',
        right: '4%',
        bottom: '3%',
        containLabel: true,
        show : true
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'value',
        reverse : true,
         stacked: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['100-90', '90-80', '70-60', '50-40'],
         stacked: true
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Female',
            type: 'bar',
            stack: 'value',
            label: {
                show: true
            },
            emphasis: {
                focus: 'series'
            },
            data: [320, 302, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320]
        },
        {
            name: 'Male',
            type: 'bar',
            stack: 'value',
            label: {
                show: true
            },
            emphasis: {
                focus: 'series'
            },
            data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
        }
    ]
};
```

and i need to be like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6lEA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the data itself:

Copy and paste the following code in the [echarts editor](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-negative):

```
option = {
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {            // 坐标轴指示器，坐标轴触发有效
            type: 'shadow'        // 默认为直线，可选为：'line' | 'shadow'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        data: ['1', '2']
    },
    grid: {
        left: '3%',
        right: '4%',
        bottom: '3%',
        containLabel: true
    },
    xAxis: [
        {
            type: 'value'
        }
    ],
    yAxis: [
        {
            type: 'category',
            axisTick: {
                show: false
            },
            data: ['g00', 'g01', 'g02', 'g03', 'g04', 'g05', 'g06', 'g07', 'g08', 'g09',
            'g10', 'g11', 'g12', 'g13', 'g14', 'g15', 'g16', 'g17']
        }
    ],
    series: [
        {
            name: '1',
            type: 'bar',
            stack: '总量',
            label: {
                show: true
            },
            emphasis: {
                focus: 'series'
            },
            data: [320, 302, 341, 374, 390, 450, 420]
        },
        {
            name: '2',
            type: 'bar',
            stack: '总量',
            label: {
                show: true,
                position: 'left'
            },
            emphasis: {
                focus: 'series'
            },
            data: [-120, -132, -101, -134, -190, -230, -210]
        }
    ]
};
```